# Using double or no quotes with wildcards

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I came across [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-find-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages/) article which attempts to explain the find command.It gives an example of

```
find /tmp -iname "data*.txt"
```

now this article [here](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0060.php) states that

> Double quotes do not suppress the substitution of words that begin
>   with "$" **but they do suppress the expansion of wildcard characters.**

Also when I tried the two commands

```
admin@localhost Downloads$ ls
gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg  mydir
admin@localhost Downloads$ find . -iname "*gall*"
./gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg
admin@localhost Downloads$ find . -iname "*gall*"  -----> A
./gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg
admin@localhost Downloads$ find . -iname *gall*    -----> B
./gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg
admin@localhost Downloads$
```

The output seems to be the same. In what case would they be different ? Why is the double quote not suppressing the expansion of the wildcard in `A` ? I was under the impression A would not work and only B would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case B:

```
find . -iname *gall*
```

The *shell* will expand `*gall*` into a list of all files matching that pattern. Since you only have one file in your current directory matching that pattern, this becomes:

```
find . -iname gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg
```

...so find will search for files matching that exact name. `foo-gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg` would not be found. If you had two or more files that match the glob, you would end up with a malformed find command; I'm pretty sure it would simply exit with an error.

In case A:

```
find . -iname "*gall*"
```

Because of the quotes, the shell *won't* expand the pattern. This just becomes (this is what `find` sees):

```
find . -iname *gall*
```

After that, the find command uses that pattern to search for all files (and directories etc.) matching that pattern. This will find both `gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg` and `foo-gallifrey-road-doctors-14437-1366x768.jpg` and every file that matches the pattern `*gall*`.

So: your command goes through the shell (which doesn't expand globs within quotes and strips away the outermost layer of quotes), and *then* goes through to `find`, which internally uses the pattern to match filenames.